# How to debug "Abort trap: 6" error with gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, sigabrt

I have a C program I compile in one of two ways: "regular" and "debug".

When I run the "regular" build, I get an `Abort trap: 6` error message, which I need to fix.

When I run the "debug" version within `gdb`, I do not get the error message and the program runs to completion.

The compilation options and flags for the "regular" build are:

```
BLDFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99
CFLAGS = -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -O3
```

The compilation flags for the "debug" build are:

```
BLDFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99
CDFLAGS = -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DDEBUG=1 -g -O0 -fno-inline
```

The "regular" and "debug" targets are compiled like so:

```
regular: setup
    $(CC) $(BLDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE) -o $(OBJDIR)/$(PROG).o $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) $(BLDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/$(PROG).o -o $(PROG) -lpthread

debug: setup
    $(CC) $(BLDFLAGS) $(CDFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE) -o $(OBJDIR)/$(PROG).o $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) $(BLDFLAGS) $(CDFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/$(PROG).o -o $(PROG) -lpthread
```

Basically, these targets are identically processed, with the exception of the `CFLAGS` and `CDFLAGS` variables.

I could post hundreds of lines of C code, but the debug code is virtually identical to the regular code, with the exception of more verbose comments that get sent to `stderr`.

Is there a component of `CDFLAGS` (the "debug" build flags) that is preventing `gdb` from being able to stop processing on `SIGABRT` (`Abort trap: 6`)?

Comment: since GDB works with an existing executable, and the gcc compiler is aborting before the executable is available, it has to be something that gcc does not like. perhaps the conflict between the inline keyword in the code and the -fno_inline parameter

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a component of CDFLAGS (the "debug" build flags) that is preventing gdb from being able to stop processing on SIGABRT

You appear to misunderstand what's happening.

It's not that GDB is not stopping on `SIGABRT`. It's that your application, when compiled without optimization, does not call `abort` in the first place!

It is not at all uncommon for application bugs to only show up in optimized builds.

On most platforms, you can add `-g` to your "regular" build, run the resulting binary under GDB, and when GDB stops on `SIGABRT`, examine the call stack with the GDB `where` command.

You can do that even without `-g`. You should still get a stack trace, but file/line info will be missing from it.

Comment: suggest always compile with all debug info, then for production, take the debug version and sue the strip command to remove all debug info.